# How to check in Nifi whether all the flowfile or messages in a process group has cleared or not?

Tags: rest, shell, curl, sh, apache-nifi

Is there a way to check whether all the messages/flow-files in a processor group has cleared or not using rest api in shell script?

Basically, my use case is that I am stopping a nifi processor in my shell script via curl command. Then I need to wait till all the queues are empty and flow files have passed through before proceeding further.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query the status of individual connections or the process group status via the API. The easiest way to do this is perform the action in your browser and use the Developer Tools to monitor the request and copy/paste this to your invoking tool.